# How to keep fixed position div aligned with centered div?

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-position

Not sure how to title the question.  I have an html structure like this:

```
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="content">
   </div>
</div>​
```

With some css like this:

```
#nav {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -100px;
    position: fixed;     
    left: 50%;
    background: red;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: blue;
}

#content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: green;
}
```

The wrapper is wider than the content, and the content is centered in the wrapper.  My problem is keeping the nav div, which is fixed to the top of the page, centered/aligned with the content div when the window is smaller than the wrapper div.  Issues arise when you scroll left and right, the fixed div stays centered in the window and the content div scrolls left and right.  I'm trying to accomplish this without javascript.

Here's a jsfiddle of what I'm running into, resize the results window to see how the nav div won't stay centered/aligned with the content div when the window is smaller than the wrapper div.

http://jsfiddle.net/p2Mzx/1/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What browser are you testing with? In Chrome this works for me.

Comment: Currently Safari, and it's not working in Chrome on my end.  Try shrinking the results window so it is smaller than the wrapper div.  I need nav to stay in line with content.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution would be to put `#nav` in your `#wrapper` and give it a horizontal margin of 25px:

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="nav"></div>
   <div id="content">
   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#nav {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 25px;
    position: fixed;  
    top: 0;   
    background: red;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: blue;
}
#content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: green;
}
```

Also see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2Mzx/11/).

Comment: If you shrink the results window and then scroll to the right the nav and content div's don't stay aligned.

Comment: Try making the result window half the size of the wrapper div then scroll to the right. The nav div and the content div do not stay aligned. Any ideas on how to keep them together? Here's a larger jsfiddle to emphasize the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/p2Mzx/24/

Comment: @codybuell You're right, I just resized the window and it seemed to work. I don't think you can solve this using css only unless you use media queries to generate a responsive design instead of a fixed one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add `margin: 0 auto` for nav too.

Then nav will be positoned to parent element just like wrapper,centered.
but removed fixed form nav. `position:fixed` makes it positioned to the browser window and out of narmal flow. Is that you want?

Answer (score 0):

It would be more appropriate to put the nav inside the wrapper, just above the content.

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="nav"></div>
   <div id="content"></div>
</div>​
```

The CSS of the nav can have left and right margins of 25px. Also absolute positioning and the width is not needed.

```
#nav {  
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
    background: red;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: blue;
}

#content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: green;
}​
```

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p2Mzx/20/

Comment: The nav div needs to stay at the top of the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can fixed the nav and content to give `padding-top`.

Consider this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knjHz/)

Comment: Try making the result window half the size of the wrapper div then scroll left and right.  The nav div and the content div do not stay aligned.  Any ideas on how to keep them together?  Here's a larger jsfiddle to emphasize the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/p2Mzx/23/